# Access: convert numerical date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have table where the date field (TimeStringID ) is in numerical format represented as the number of seconds that have past since 12:00am March 1,1980.

In SQL Server the command is `DATEADD(s, CAST(TimeStringID AS numeric), '1980-03-01') AS 'StartTime'`

The field **1289260817.0000000501** converts to **2021-01-07 00:00:17.000** using the above SQL Server statement.

How would I convert this for Access queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the equivalent:

```
 select dateadd("s", TimeStringId, #03/01/1980#)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, returns `11/8/1940 12:00:17 AM`.

Comment: Which might be because `1980-03-01` and `12/31/1899` are quite different dates...

Comment: Yes, need to use `#3/1/1980#` to get the SQLServer result.

Comment: Using dd/mm/yyyy `#1/3/1980#` returns `11/10/2020 12:00:17 AM`. I used mm/dd/yyyy `#3/1/1980#`. `#1980/3/1#` works also and removes ambiguity. Although, return for both is mm/dd/yyyy `1/7/2021 12:00:17 AM`.